# Why do colors not show up as expected in plotly in R

Tags: r, plotly, visualization

```
library(plotly)

fig <- plot_ly()
fig <- fig %>% add_markers(
  x = 1,
  y = 1,
  col = "gray"
)
fig <- fig %>% add_markers(
  x = 1, 
  y = 2,
  col = "blue"
)
> fig
```

For some reason, the `gray` is showing up as blue, and the `blue` is showing up as orange. How do I specify different colors for different data points?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify the `color` in `marker` -

```
library(plotly)

fig <- plot_ly()
fig <- fig %>% add_markers(
  x = 1,
  y = 1,
  marker = list(color = "gray", size = 10)
)
fig <- fig %>% add_markers(
  x = 1, 
  y = 2,
  marker = list(color = "blue", size = 10)
)
fig
```

[image]